# TypeScript Angular ReactiveForms 2 way property binding

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-reactive-forms

Good Morning,

I am building a webApplication with Angular 6, Java Spring and a mysql Database.
I built a form which will be used for both creating and updating customer data.

On creating a customer, the data is passed to the server using REST, this works well as google's console output's for my request is a json string which associates the form model and the data typed into that form.

My problem is on updating, i populate the form with a client data but when i submit, google's console outputs an empty object in my post request.

My form :

```
<div class="container spacer borders" *ngIf="showClientForm">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="updateClient(this.form.value)">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <p><b>Edition Client</b></p>
        <input  type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="name" 
                placeholder="Raison sociale ou Nom et Prénom" 
                [(value)]="selectedClient.nom"
                formControlName = "nom"
                />
        <input  type="text" 
                class="form-control small-spacer" 
                id="email" 
                placeholder="Raison sociale ou Nom et Prénom" 
                [(value)]="selectedClient.email"
                formControlName = "email"
                />
      </div>
      <div class="form-check-inline col-md-6">
        <input  class="form-check-input" 
                type="radio" 
                id="type_particulier" 
                name="typeClient" 
                [(value)]="selectedClient.value"
                formControlName = "typeClient"
                />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="type_particulier">
          Particulier
        </label>
        <input  class="form-check-input spacer-left" 
                type="radio" 
                name="typeClient" 
                id="type_professionnel" 
                [(value)]="selectedClient.value"
                formControlName="typeClient"
                />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="type_professionnel">
          Professionnel
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row spacer">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 spacer" formGroupName="adresseFacturation">
        <p><b>Adresse Facturation</b></p>
        <input  type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="adr_fact" 
                placeholder="Numéro, voie ..." 
                [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseFacturation.rue"
                formControlName="rue"
                />
        <input  type="text" 
                class="form-control small-spacer" 
                id="adr_fact" 
                placeholder="Complément d'adresse" 
                [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseFacturation.complement"
                formControlName="complement"
                />
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input  type="text" 
                    class="form-control small-spacer" 
                    id="gc_cp" 
                    placeholder="Code Postal" 
                    [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseFacturation.codePostal"
                    formControlName="codePostal"
                    />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input  type="text" 
                    class="form-control small-spacer" 
                    id="gc_ville" 
                    placeholder="Ville" 
                    [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseFacturation.ville"
                    formControlName="ville"
                    />
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 spacer" formGroupName="adresseTravaux">
          <p><b>Adresse Travaux</b></p>
          <input  type="text" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  id="adr_fact" 
                  placeholder="Numéro, voie ..." 
                  [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseTravaux.rue"
                  formControlName="rue"
                  />
          <input  type="text" 
                  class="form-control small-spacer" 
                  id="adr_fact" 
                  placeholder="Complément d'adresse" 
                  [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseTravaux.complement"
                  formControlName="complement"
                  />
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input  type="text" 
                      class="form-control small-spacer" 
                      id="gc_cp" 
                      placeholder="Code Postal" 
                      [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseTravaux.codePostal"
                      formControlName="codePostal"
                      />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input  type="text" 
                      class="form-control small-spacer" 
                      id="gc_ville" 
                      placeholder="Ville" 
                      [(value)]="selectedClient.adresseTravaux.ville"
                      formControlName="ville"
                      />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
      <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
      <button class="btn btn-dark spacer-left" type="button" (click)="returnToList()">Retour</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

when i remove `[(value)]="selectedClient.nom"` on each input field, i can create a customer with that form, but when I try to bind the value property in order to populate the value with a customer for updating this value then the form model does not take it in account.

Here is my component .ts  which includes the model:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../services/client.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gest-clients',
  templateUrl: './gest-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gest-clients.component.css']
})
export class GestClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  clients:Array<Object> = [];
  selectedClient;
  showClientForm = false;
  showNewClientForm = false;
  form:FormGroup;
  msg;


  constructor(private clientService:ClientService,
              private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.GetClientList().subscribe(
      data => this.handleContent(data)
    );
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'id':'',
      'nom':'',
      'email':'',
      'adresseFacturation' : this.formBuilder.group({
        'id':'',
        'rue':'',
        'complement':'',
        'ville':'',
        'codePostal':'',
        'complementCodePostal':'',
        'supprimer':''
      }),
      'adresseTravaux' : this.formBuilder.group({
        'id':'',
        'rue':'',
        'complement':'',
        'ville':'',
        'codePostal':'',
        'complementCodePostal':'',
        'supprimer':''
      }),
      'typeClient':'',
      'supprimer':''
    });




  }

  selectClient(client){
    this.showClientForm = true;
    this.selectedClient = client;
  }

  deleteClient(Client){

  }

  handleContent(data){
    this.clients = data;
  }

  updateClient(data){
    console.log(data) **// Empty json string (model only) KO**
    this.clientService.updClient(data).subscribe(
      res => this.msg = res,
      error => this.msg = error
    )
  }

  returnToList(){
    this.form.reset()
    this.selectedClient = null;
    this.showClientForm = false;
    this.showNewClientForm = false;

  }

  addNew(){
    this.showNewClientForm = true;
  }

  AddNewClient(clientFormData){
    console.log(clientFormData) // Correct json string (model + data) ok
    this.clientService.CreateNewClient(clientFormData).subscribe(
      res => this.msg = res,
      error => this.msg = error
    )

  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { DevisComponent } from './devis/devis.component';
import { CommandeComponent } from './commande/commande.component';
import { GestDevisComponent } from './gest-devis/gest-devis.component';
import { GestCommandeComponent } from './gest-commande/gest-commande.component';
import { GestClientsComponent } from './gest-clients/gest-clients.component';
import { GestFournisseursComponent } from './gest-fournisseurs/gest-fournisseurs.component';
import { GestMaterielsComponent } from './gest-materiels/gest-materiels.component';
import { GestPrestationsComponent } from './gest-prestations/gest-prestations.component';
import { MaterielComponent } from './materiel/materiel.component';
import { PrestationComponent } from './prestation/prestation.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ClientService } from './services/client.service';

const routes = [
  {path:"", component:HomeComponent},
  {path:"devis", component:DevisComponent},
  {path:"commande", component:CommandeComponent},
  {path:"materiel", component:MaterielComponent},
  {path:"prestation", component:PrestationComponent},
  {path:"gestDevis", component:GestDevisComponent},
  {path:"gestCommandes", component:GestCommandeComponent},
  {path:"gestFournisseurs", component:GestFournisseursComponent},
  {path:"gestMateriels", component:GestMaterielsComponent},
  {path:"gestClients", component:GestClientsComponent},
  {path:"gestPrestations", component:GestPrestationsComponent}

]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    DevisComponent,
    CommandeComponent,
    GestDevisComponent,
    GestCommandeComponent,
    GestClientsComponent,
    GestFournisseursComponent,
    GestMaterielsComponent,
    GestPrestationsComponent,
    MaterielComponent,
    PrestationComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ClientService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I suggest you to implement proper Reactive Forms using FormGroup and FormControl as explained in the official Angular doc : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
Then your input looks like this : `<input type="text" formControlName="firstName">`

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, I will work on it. added my app.module.ts on my question

Comment: You were right , with proper implementation everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm glad to here that. I'll write a clean answer today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in the angular documentation.  As the documentation suggests, you should not define directly the form tag attribute value directly in html but you should use the setValue/patchvalue method in your .ts . This method sets the default value of in each FormControl in your form. I also found the solution for setting the value for the embedded elements in my form. My code is not the most beautifull but it works so far :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../services/client.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gest-clients',
  templateUrl: './gest-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gest-clients.component.css']
})
export class GestClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  clients:Array<Object> = [];
  selectedClient;
  showClientForm = false;
  showNewClientForm = false;
  form:FormGroup;
  msg;


  constructor(private clientService:ClientService,
              private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.GetClientList().subscribe(
      data => this.handleContent(data)
    );
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'id':'',
      'nom':'',
      'email':'',
      'adresseFacturation' : this.formBuilder.group({
        'id':'',
        'rue':'',
        'complement':'',
        'ville':'',
        'codePostal':'',
        'complementCodePostal':'',
        'supprimer':''
      }),
      'adresseTravaux' : this.formBuilder.group({
        'id':'',
        'rue':'',
        'complement':'',
        'ville':'',
        'codePostal':'',
        'complementCodePostal':'',
        'supprimer':''
      }),
      'typeClient':'',
      'supprimer':''
    });

  }


  selectClient(client){
    this.showClientForm = true;
    this.selectedClient = client;

    // sets the default value for the first lyer of elements in my form model
    this.form.patchValue({
      'id':this.selectedClient.id,
      'nom':this.selectedClient.nom,
      'email':this.selectedClient.email,
      'typeClient':this.selectedClient.typeClient,
      'supprimer':this.selectedClient.supprimer
    });

    // sets the default value for embedded elements in the form model 
    // Invoicing address
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['id'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.id);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['rue'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.rue);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['complement'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.complement);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['ville'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.ville);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['codePostal'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.codePostal);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['complementCodePostal'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.complementCodePostal);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseFacturation']).controls['supprimer'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseFacturation.supprimer);
    // works address

    // handling null value 
    if(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux==null){
      (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['id'].patchValue("");
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['rue'].patchValue("");
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['complement'].patchValue("");
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['ville'].patchValue("");
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['codePostal'].patchValue("");
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['complementCodePostal'].patchValue("");
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['supprimer'].patchValue("");
    }else{
      (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['id'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.id);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['rue'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.rue);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['complement'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.complement);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['ville'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.ville);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['codePostal'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.codePostal);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['complementCodePostal'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.complementCodePostal);
    (<FormGroup>this.form.controls['adresseTravaux']).controls['supprimer'].patchValue(this.selectedClient.adresseTravaux.supprimer);
    }




    /**
     * Information found from another post in stackoverflow which led me onto the right way of using setValue or PatchValue
     * 
     * . Using setValue()

    this.userForm.setValue({name: 'Mahesh', age: '20' });

    It is necessary to mention all from controls in setValue() otherwise it will throw error. 

    2. Using patchValue()

    this.userForm.patchValue({name: 'Mahesh'}); 

    When we use patchValue() then it is not necessary to mention all form controls.
    */


  }

  deleteClient(Client){

  }

  handleContent(data){
    this.clients = data;
  }

  updateClient(data){
    console.log(data)
    this.clientService.updClient(data).subscribe(
      res => this.msg = res,
      error => this.msg = error
    )
  }

  returnToList(){
    this.form.reset()
    this.selectedClient = null;
    this.showClientForm = false;
    this.showNewClientForm = false;

  }

  addNew(){
    this.showNewClientForm = true;
  }

  AddNewClient(clientFormData){
    console.log(clientFormData)
    this.clientService.CreateNewClient(clientFormData).subscribe(
      res => this.msg = res,
      error => this.msg = error
    )

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Salut Philippe,

just change your ngSubmit and remove the parameter =>
    (ngSubmit)="updateClient()"

reflect this change in updateClient() and simply use this.form

```
updateClient(){
  console.log(this.form.value) // ** should print your updated customer object
  etc ...
}
```

A+
Philippe

Comment: prints out an empty object with just the model, property [(value)]="selectedClient.nom" is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parentheses () from the property binding and use square brackets only.

```
<input  type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="adr_fact" 
            placeholder="Numéro, voie ..." 
            [value]="selectedClient.adresseFacturation.rue"
            formControlName="rue"
            />
```

Comment: Good Evening, I came to the parenthesis because I read that they acted as listener for a value change in the input. Thanks for your proposal but I have already tried this before asking the question.